# Iterating over a multiple files in a folder

Tags: python, excel

Im trying to develop a program that can iterate over different files in the same folder. The files are all the same format but will have different names. Right now if there is only 1 file in the folder the code executes with no problems but with different files i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Downloads/FYP/Feedback draft.py", line 24, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
  File "C:\Users\shomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\shomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\shomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\shomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tester2.xlsx'
```

The code im using is :

```
directory = r'D:\Downloads\FYP\TEST'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        sh1=wb['test']

        doc = DocxTemplate('Assignment1feedback.docx')
        context = {
            'acc': acceleration
        }
         doc.render(context)
        doc.save('D:\\Downloads\\FYP\\TEST\\' + filename + '.docx')
```

This is incomplete code as the full thing would be quite long but overall i want to access these excel files and then create a corresponding docx

Comment: hi perhaps use `os.path.join(directory, filename)` to generate a complete path

Comment: Hi Not sure what you mean by this

Comment: Since `listdir` returns filenames without the directory part, you can prepend the path when you open them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) only provides the basename of the directory files, which will cause problems if your working directory does not match the value of `directory`. If your working directory is `D:\Downloads`, `./file.xlsx` does not exist but `D:\Downloads\FYP\TEST/file.xlsx` does.

You will want to use the absolute path to the file, you have two options here. You could follow @IronMan's suggestion in the their comment to produce the file path from the directory path and file basename:

```py
import os

directory = r'D:\Downloads\FYP\TEST'

for filename in os.listdir():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(directory, filename))
```

This is a simple and useful approach; however, its functionality is somewhat limited and may make it harder to make changes in the future. The alternative is to use python's [`paathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and [`scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir), and access the path directly from there:

```py
import pathlib

directory = r'D:\Downloads\FYP\TEST'

for entry in pathlib.scandir(diectory):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(entry.path)
```

Comment: Thanks bro for the help